# What worst outcomes Derek Chauvin can expect on appeals?

Tags: criminal-law

Will Derek Chauvin's situation get worse on unsuccessful appeals? Is there a rule, law, or reasons that prevent him from going deeper into the appeal process to gain a more favorable/lenient ruling?

Answer (score 8):

He cannot be given a higher sentence because he appealed. If the appeal is unsuccessful, he will be in exactly the same legal position as if he had not appealed, aside from any legal fees an costs he may incur for the appeal.

The worst that could happen to Chauvin  at the end of the appeals process, is that all three convictions are upheld, which leaves him no worse off than if there had been no appeal.

However, if an appeal is successful, it will probably lead to a new trial. In general, when an accused person is retried after a successful appeal, there is the possibility of a worse outcome.  In this case, however, Chauvin was convicted on all counts charged, so the outcome could not get worse.

If Chauvin were to appeal and get a new trial, but be convicted in a new trial, he could in theory receive a larger sentence after the second trial. But since the charges would be the same, the range of possible sentences and the sentencing guidelines would be the same. Of course, no one yet knows what sentence the judge will impose after the current conviction.

Comment: Can't the prosecution appeal if the judge vacates some of the convictions?  That would make the appeal process risky, would it not?

Comment: @grovkin  The worst that could happen to Chauvin  at the end of the appeals process, is that all three convictions are upheld, which leaves him no worse off than if there had been no appeal.

Comment: Yes. If the judge vacates a conviction, the prosecution can appeal, but all it can get from that appeal is reinstatement of the original conviction. There's basically nothing additional the prosecution can obtain as a result of a defendant's appeal.

Comment: At the moment Derek Chauvin is a man with "no previous convictions". But there were 18 serious complaints made against him, non properly investigated, probably because it was the word of a petty criminal against the word of a highly regarded police officer. Now it's the word of a petty criminal against the word of a convicted murderer. This includes one case where he put his knee on the neck of a handcuffed woman. Any of these cases could lead to an assault conviction, and by the time sentencing for the murder case happens, he would be a man with "previous convictions".

Comment: Are the federal sentencing guidelines more strict than the state in this case? Also, how the maximum sentence is calculated - the maximum penalty for each count add together, or the maximum from one of the 3 counts he was charged with?